# Implementing more than one spinner

Tags: android, spinner

i am trying to add multiple spinner but when i am trying to select it shows blank transparent dialog...

here is code what i have tried please help.

(outside onCreate)

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

     switch(parent.getId()){
        case R.id.spinner1:
            ArrayAdapter arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter(VideoPlaybackActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,vlaues);  
         arrayadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
           spiner.setAdapter(arrayadapter);


        spiner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                 String s1= spiner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   timer.setText(s1);
             }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
         }
        );

            break;
        case R.id.spinner2:
            ArrayAdapter arrayadapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(VideoPlaybackActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,typeArray);  
             arrayadapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
               spinner2.setAdapter(arrayadapter1);


            spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                     String s1= spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

                 }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
             }
            );
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

here is values and typeArray

```
    String vlaues[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};

  String typeArray[] = {"pic1","pic2","pic3"};
```

i am trying to shows these two array on spinner ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s simply error in the application logic. You set a spinner adapter after a spinner item was selected:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch(parent.getId()){
    case R.id.spinner1:
        ArrayAdapter arrayadapter = ... 
        spiner.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
        spiner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){...});
        break;

...
```

You need to set adapters and OnItemSelectedListener for spinners before getting onItemSelected callback.